# python mock class attributes are not accessible

Tags: python, mocking

When mocking a class object I can't access it's attributes.
I've read a lot of documentation but I'm new to mocking and don't see the problem with this code. I expect x and y to return the same value 1e-15

```
class test_user_data:
    scale = 1e-15

class test_signal(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('xx.user_data', autospec=test_user_data, spec_set=True)
    def test_data(self, mock_user_data):
        x = xx.user_data()
        y = test_user_data()
        print(x.scale)
        print(y.scale)
```

but I get

```
<NonCallableMagicMock name='user_data().timescale' spec_set='float' id='47213638195072'>
1e-15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autospec` and spec'ing in general is used to define an API. When using a `Mock`, you can pretty much call or access any attribute on it and it'll just let you. It will return another mock object though.

See something like this:

```
>>> my_mock = Mock()
>>> my_mock.stuff
<Mock name='mock.stuff' id='139870989908344'>
>>> my_mock.junk()
<Mock name='mock.junk()' id='139870987197912'>
```

If I define a spec, it says you can't access things that don't actually exist on the real class. Like so:

```
>>> my_mock = Mock(spec=xx.user_data)
>>> my_mock.stuff
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/unittest/mock.py", line 574, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError("Mock object has no attribute %r" % name)
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'stuff'
>>> my_mock.scale
<Mock name='mock.scale' id='139871128095264'>
```

So the above shows you can't access an attribute on the Mock that isn't defined in the actual `user_data` class because I've used spec.

That explains how autospec works, but what you actually want is the `return_value` arg. Go ahead and add it to your patch decorator and you should be all set. It should look like this:

```
@patch('xx.user_data', autospec=test_user_data, spec_set=True, return_value=test_user_data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, your solution solves the problem. If test_user_data had a __init__ method, is there way to force mock to run it?

Comment: I think it would take a little bit of hacking around to get exactly what you want, but I do believe it's possible yes. What's the end goal of what you're trying to accomplish with that? Do you actually want to test `__init__`? Or you want the effect of `__init__` to happen on the mock object? I'd encourage you to take a look at `.side_effect` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide It will allow you to assign function pointers (a function pointer to the original `__init__` in this case) and might accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: @Damo given the complexity, and if the above link doesn't completely solve it, you may want to consider opening a new question for this as well.

Comment: Thanks @wholevinski. Your response fixes the issue for basic user_data. I also have more complex user_data with additional fields and dependencies between them, these fields are initialized in `__init__`. Using `side_effect` works. Which gives: `@patch('xx.user_data', autospec=test_user_data, return_value=test_user_data, side_effect=test_user_data.__init__(test_user_data))`